# Android ArrayList - Adding items one by one results in IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I use following function to animate filtering a list (actually I once found that somewhere, don't know where anymore):

```
 public void animateTo(List<T> items) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(items);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(items);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(items);
}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<T> newItems) {
    for (int i = mListItems.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final T item = mListItems.get(i);
        if (!newItems.contains(item)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<T> newItems) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newItems.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final T item = newItems.get(i);
        if (!mListItems.contains(item)) {
            addItem(i, item);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<T> newItems) {
    for (int toPosition = newItems.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final T item = newItems.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = mListItems.indexOf(item);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

 public T removeItem(int position) {
    final T item = mListItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return item;
}

public void addItem(int position, T item) {
    mListItems.add(position, item); // <- EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final T model = mListItems.remove(fromPosition);
    mListItems.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}
```

Sometimes I get an exception like following in the `addItem` function:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 203, size is 201
```

**Actually, how can this happen? The loop in `applyAndAnimateAdditions` begins at 0, adds items one by one if they are not already in the list. How can the index exception occur?**

Comment: Where do you make sure, that `mListItems` and `newItems` have the same size?

Comment: They don't have to. I only call animateTo... the order of the three calls in there makes sure, that I first remove all items that are not in the filtered list anymore , then I add all new items and then I move all items that already have been in the list but have a new position now

Comment: Either I'm stupid or your logic makes no sense (at least to me): You have two lists with unknown sizes. First you iterate over list 1 and remove everything that is not in list 2. Then you iterate over list 2 and add everything that is not already in list 1 to that list using a specific index. This second "feature" fails if the "new stuff" has a greater index than the size of list 1. So I still don't get the logic behind that :(.

Comment: The second would fail if that can happen, yes. But I add all items to list 1 if they are not already in it so list 1 should always be at least as big as the current iterator index...

Comment: No, not really. I can add the same item a hundred times to list 2 and list 1 only needs one of them to satisfy the check `mListItems.contains(item)`. So the next new item of list 2 can be on index *100*, but list 1 still has one item on index *0*. Also, have you overriden the `equals` and `hashCode` methods correctly in your "item" class? (if it is a selfwritten class and not an existing one)

Comment: Your are right. Didn't write that the list has unique values only... I forget that. And yes I have custom functions for equal and hash, and the data is based on all contacts in a person's phone book and the equal and hash use the Id from the phone book contact...

Comment: I think that's the only reason this function could fail, a not unique list... still I can't imagine how this can happen with data based on the phone book...

Comment: *"Didn't write that the list has unique values only"* Then I suggest to use one of the `Set` implementations. You don't need to bother about uniqueness yourself, since the set will do that for you. Also, add a `try/catch` block in your `addItem` method, write something to the `catch` block and set a breakpoint there. Then start the debugger, it stops if the exception was thrown and then check the content of both lists to see what is going one.

Comment: *"I think that's the only reason this function could fail, a not unique list"* Yes, looks like this is the problem. But to be sure, try the debugger like I suggested and if it really is the problem, then either re-think your "unique"-check (there might be an unchecked `add` call) or use a `Set`.

Comment: I will have to add some debug functions to my app... it's in use by thousands and this filter is called very often... but the exception is only thrown rarely... I can't reproduce it either. .

Comment: Well, if this happens rarely, then the faulty code is called rarely, or you can have a race condition (two (or more) threads writing to the same list). Do you work with threads?

Comment: The input list Is calculated asynchron but the display is synchron... I think it's possible rare because the not unique data is rare .. the function is used quite often...

Comment: Well, still try the `try/catch` block and print the content of both lists instead of setting a breakpoint. So then the problem occurs you will now what both lists contain and if the items are really non-unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to check if the `position` is equal or larger(`>=`) to the `ArrayLists` `size` just add the item to the end of the `Arraylist`.

```
public void addItem(int position, T item) {
    if(position >= mListItems.size())
        mListItems.add(mListItems.size()-1, item);
    else
        mListItems.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

So here's your problem you are iterating through `newItems` but you are adding to `mListItems`

Comment: I know a solution to it... as you say, that's what I can do. But still, I'm wondering what the problem is... As I don't see it. It should not happen, never... I would like to know what I don't see as well...

Comment: from which method are you calling the addItem method ?

Comment: I edited my answer with the following: So here's your problem you are iterating through newItems but you are adding to mListItems

Comment: Correct. BUT if mListItems does not contain an entry of new items , I add this entry to mListItems so mListItems should always at least have as many items as the iterator counter... it's growing while iterating...

Comment: Are you possibly calling this in an asynchronous way?

Comment: No. Synchronous. Calculating the input list is done asynchronous, but using the result is done synchronous